How to connect Obs with zegocloud streaming service
I am using zegocloud's prebuild ui, react, node for this project
I have created a streaming platform everything is working there
I want to add a feature where they can stream through obs software but the issue is it is asking for a rtmp link which i dont have i have this link wss://webliveroom**********-api.coolzcloud.com/ws  but as this is a websocket link this won't work how to do it
I tried connecting obs with this link wss://webliveroom**********-api.coolzcloud.com/ws
by replacing wss with rtmp but nothing happened as this is not the link
i tried connecting directly with my link of website and yet its showing failed Screenshot of failure :)
please someone help me or guide me how to do it
